# After each View Item

Tags: views

I made a block using the Views module, that displays 3 blog posts. It only displays the title and the teaser, and I want to add a "Read More" after each blog post teaser. I can only see how to add a footer to the end of the whole block, not after each listed item. Is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, add a Node: Link field, turn off the label, and set the Text To Display to "Read More" and you should be set.